# Recovering cache mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, caching, recovery

I have just destroyed an entire style.css file on a server. I was really tired and managed to delete the entire thing.. Now i need to recover this somehow. I have already pressed ctrl + f5 to view the changes but ofcourse i broke the entire thing.

I am using mozilla firefox and have tried using about:cache in the browser window but it only displayed the empty version of style.css.

Do you guys think i could locate the mozilla firefox cache folder and try recovering the entire folder searching for the file. But i have heard that firefox is using a security feature that doesn't name the files in original file names and extensions?

Id be grateful for any help!! Thanks

Comment: Try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html, but I am not sure if this will work for your lost file. Perhaps this https://www.piriform.com/recuva will give you access to older versions of the style

Comment: I have tried it already it didn't find it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to scavange the file using this software http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html on another company pc that still had it in the cache.

But lesson of the story is have backup and do use git!! Will save you a lot of hassle.